# Reducir codigo con LinQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo un método realizado con Linq el cual necesito recuperar el primer elemento, en este caso el nombre de un Personaje. El archivo al que le hago la "consulta" es un `.json` y justo esta consulta devuelve 0 elementos.

Según lo tengo funciona, pero veo el código mal implementado y de seguro se puede mejorar con alguna función Linq.

```
    public static void Ejer8(List<Heroe> h)
    {
        var nombre = h.Where(x => x.Gender == "Male" && x.Hp > 100 && x.Level == 10).ToList();

        if(nombre.Min() != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nombre[0].Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No existe ningun heroe");
        }     
    }
```

¿Como podría mejorarlo? Reduciendo las lineas de código. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias usar el metodo **[FirstOrDefault](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8)** que obtiene el primer elemento concordante con las condiciones que le entregas.

```
var nombre = h.Where(x => x.Gender == "Male" && x.Hp > 100 && x.Level == 10).FirstOrDefault();
```

O

```
var nombre = h.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Gender == "Male" && x.Hp > 100 && x.Level == 10);
```

Con el **[ToList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8)** estas obteniendo un listado por defecto, ten en cuenta eso.

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas

Comment: Sii, me viene perfecto. Gracias!